# Invoking a function in an iframe from the parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I am building a website with no server-side
I have a main page with an iframe and on a button click I want the iframe's src to change and a function in it to be invoked with a passed parameter.

The function is not called for some reason.

here's my code:

the iframe:

```
<iframe id="main_area_frame" name="main_area_frame" src="" frameborder="0" width="100%"     height="100%"></iframe>
```

the onclick function:

```
function onSubMenuClick(images)
{
    //Set Images Frame
    main_area = document.getElementById("main_area_frame");
    main_area.src = "ImagesFrame.html";
    main_area.contentWindow.initializeImages(images);
}
```

the function in the iframe(ImagesFrame.html):

```
function initializeImages(imagesStr) 
{
    alert("initializeImages");
    ...
}
```

some weird things I noticed are that

when adding an alert just before main_area.contentWindow.initializeImages(images);
the function is somehow called successfully.

if I set the iframe's src from the begining and skip the line main_area.src = "ImagesFrame.html"; - the function is again, called.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is the cause, but I would try putting a delay(sleep) between

```
main_area.src = "ImagesFrame.html";
```

and

```
main_area.contentWindow.initializeImages(images);
```

in order to allow the iframe to be rendered (I do not know if it is the rendered by the same frame or the browser launches a new one).

Just my two cents.

Comment: You are correct that the iframe is load asynchronously and that's the cause of the problem.  But, rather than a delay, I think they should listen for the onload event on the iframe and when that has fired, then it's safe to manipulate the contents of the iframe.

Comment: Of course jfriend00 method is more robust than mine; mine just works as a quick test of the cause. For production, better use jfriend00 proposal.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with publishing the function from the child iframe during
onload handling.  For example, (substituting your *funcName*):

In child iframe, edit body tag (or use equivalent javascript)

```
  <body onload='top.funcName = funcName'>
```

In parent page, edit javascript; now the
*funcName* will be generally accessible as,
    `value = top.funcName( )`